# What is the theory behind, Elasticsearch indexing the unstructured data like pdf files?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have read about full-text searches from `elasticsearch` [documentation](http://www.elastic.co) but not able to understand the algorithm it uses for indexing pdf files.

Comment: what is your question exactly? Do you want to know how elastic store and search on pdf?

Comment: @hkulekci Yeah the algorithm used by elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood Elasticsearch uses the [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) library, that do all the text extraction from the different file types, and PDF parser in Tika uses the [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) Java library to extract the text from pdf format specifically. So, after some magic done by this open source library, the extracted text are indexed as a normal Elasticsearch document.